# align divs on center/left

Tags: html, css

Can somebody please help me with this piece of code?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="block"> </div>
  <div class="block"> </div>
  <div class="block"> </div>
  <div class="block"> </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {
  margin:auto;
  text-align:center;
  padding:10%;
}
.block {
  width:240px;
  height:300px;
  background: red;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LBabj/)

I want it so that the whole container aligned in the middle but when there is an extra block at the bottom, it should go to the left. Is that possible?

Comment: One of the problem is that you have multiple divs with the same id! That's not valid, ids must be unique; you should use classes.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning about ids and classes, i did this very quickly to post the question!

Comment: please take a look at this screenshot for explanation! I hope this helps: http://i.imgur.com/POqgA.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem with @media queries :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 840px) {
.portfolio_container {
    width:512px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 580px) {
.portfolio_container {
    width:255px;
    }
}
```

I know media queries are not compatible with older browser versions! but at least it is supported by all most recent versions!

Answer (score 3):

This works:

**HTML:**

```
#container {
  margin:auto;
  text-align:center;
  width:70px;
  overflow:hidden;}
```

**CSS:**

```
.block {
  width:24px;
  height:30px;
  float:left;
  margin:5px 5px;
  background: red;}
```

See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LBabj/2/) here. I changed the sizes so that it's easier to see but you can readjust them according to your site. Basically, you need `overflow:hidden;` and set the width of the container so that it can only fit 2 blocks per row so that the next block goes underneath and is aligned to the left. Also, remember that ids must be unique in your page; if you need more than one element with the same definition then you must use classes.

Comment: Im sorry im posting from my phone at the moment, i did take a look at your answer! I want to have more than 2 blocks per row, it should be dynamic, it should add more blocks per row depending on the size of the window!  When the window is wide, i need to fit as many as possible and drops them to the next row accordingly as the window gets smaller!

Comment: And about id vs class, my mistake, i did this quickly to post the question

Comment: Well then that's a confusing question. If you want to achieve what you describe then simply add a wrapper around the container. Here's an updated fiddle that does what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/LBabj/9/

Comment: This is still not right, thats similar to what I had in my question! you basically got the idea right but I want it to be centered on the page!! If i float the blocks left, the container is not centered anymore! please take at the screenshots:

http://i.imgur.com/POqgA.jpg

Comment: You cannot align a floated element relative to a parent element.

Comment: I see what you mean. Is the width of the container equal to the width of the page or is the container wrapped inside some other element?

Answer (score 1):

I would use `float: left` in block id,remove container from css and use class instead of id because id must be used once:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="block"> </div>
    <div class="block"> </div>
    <div class="block"> </div>
    <div class="block"> </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.block {
    width:40%;
    height:300px;
    margin: 5%;
    float: left;
    background: red;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: I know, but the html from the question has multiple id block

Comment: **+1** Great Answer. But do please add in an extra `block`, as OP wants to see odd number. Cheers!

Comment: This wont work, my blocks will have fixed width, and as the browser window get bigger, it should add more blocks to the row accordingly, and if the window is smaller, it drops them to the next row! Its going to be a picture gallery

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin for jQuery to help you organize the DIV.
desGridLayout:
http://des.delestesoft.com:8080/?go=8

Comment: You shouldn't need a plug-in when CSS can do the job!

Comment: What this plugin does is more than a CSS.
What it does create a grid and to organize according to the user's screen.
Example if the user resizes the screen or does everything reoarginza scroll automatically.

Comment: Yea, I know but that's not the right tool when all you need is simple positioning.

Comment: Downvoted. This question is about CSS and not about JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: I will try this when i get home and let you know